# How to upload file in any directory with PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I have created image uploading codes and they're only allowing me to upload image into only directory that is in the same directory as PHP file.

```
$profile = 'profiles/'.$_FILES['profile']['name'];
```

if I change it like this:

```
$profile = 'php_codes/profiles/'.$_FILES['profile']['name'];
```

it shows me error. I'm using `copy()` function to upload it.
Please help me to get to know how to upload it in any directory even into any other partition. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you should share that error with us.

Comment: Reading the error message would be the first step.  Also examining the exact runtime values of the code you're using.

Comment: what does the structure look like ?

Comment: it could be due to permission set on folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally got it! Just using ../profiles and then directory is making it. You just write dots (2) then times you want to go back. If two times, ../../profiles. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide the error, but it's very likely that the error you are getting is that the directory that you are attempting to copy the file to does not exist. It could also be permission problems, but your confusion seems to be over building a path.

The problem with your code is that your path is **relative** to the PHP file's location, rather than being a direct path from your root directory. You should read a little bit about how to navigate file structures, but these are the three key things to remember when working in a *nix file system (such as Linux):

1. If your file path does not start with a slash, then the path will be relative to the directory that the PHP script is in.
2. If you start your file path with a slash, the path will be relative to the root directory.
3. You start a path with one or more `../`, to traverse to a parent directory.

---

So for example, let's say you have these three directories, with your PHP script residing in `/php_codes`:

- /php_codes
- /php_codes/code_snippets
- /profiles

---

If you wanted to copy the file to `php_codes`, your path would be relative to the PHP script:

```
$profiles = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
```

---

If you wanted to copy the file to `php_codes/code_snippets`, again you could just do it relative to your PHP script:

```
$profiles = "code_snippets/" . $_FILES['profile']['name'];
```

However, this is an opportunity to also show how you might do it with an absolute path from the root directory. You could use this (note the slash at the beginning of the path):

```
$profiles = "/php_scripts/code_snippets/" . $_FILES['profile']['name'];
```

---

If you want to copy the file to `/profiles`, which is outside of the `/php_codes` directory, there are two ways you can do it.

The first way is with an absolute path from the root directory (path begins with a slash), just like the example above:

```
$profiles = "/profiles/ " . $_FILES['profile']['name'];
```

Or, you can make it relative, by using `../` to go up one level to the parent directory:

```
$profiles = "../profiles/ " . $_FILES['profile']['name'];
```

---

A quick note about using `../` to go up one directory: you can repeat that as many times as needed, to continue going up a level. For example, if your PHP script was located inside of `/php_codes/code_snippets`, but you wanted to copy a file to `/profiles`, then you would have to go up two levels:

```
$profiles = "../../profiles/ " . $_FILES['profile']['name'];
```

Comment: I used that $profiles = "../profiles/ " . $_FILES['profile']['name']; but not still working! It says directory did not found and I tried to change my function from copy() to move_uploaded_file() function but still not working! It just saves it in the same folder which is in the same folder as php file too

Comment: @JeanMarie As the error message indicates, there is no directory called `profiles` in the __parent directory__ (because you used `../`) of your PHP script. Have you already created that directory, or made sure that it does exist?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$profiles=__DIR__ . "/profiles/" . $_FILES['profile']['name'];
```

that will work as **DIR** will be your script directory and then it will be absolute path